# delete key on linux does not work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, input

My delete key does not work in ubuntu, it does nothing. I understand that this is a common problem, but I could not solve it with the information I found elsewhere.

I ran xev.
Pressing the 'a' key gives:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x1a6, subw 0x0, time 7255643, (-113,-107), root:(425,300),
    state 0x2010, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Pressing 'Delete' gives:

```
FocusOut event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

From there I don't know what to do. Help?

---

**--- Edit ---**

More details:
Ubuntu Hardy, studio edition.

The keyboard is a Logitech UltraX (967498), wireless. I couldn't find it on logitech's page, but here it is: [UltraX](http://www.oninocomputing.co.uk/keyboards/logitech_ultra_x_967498_0120_9674980120.html)

---

**--- Edit 2 ---**

Pressing Delete in a virtual terminal after `showkey -s`:

```
0xe0 0x53
0xe0 0xd3
```

After `showkey -k`:

```
0x6f
0xef
```

(First rows at press down, second row at release).

---

**--- Edit 3 ---**

```
gauthier@ubuntu:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep -i delete
keycode  91 = KP_Delete KP_Decimal KP_Delete KP_Separator
keycode 107 = Delete
gauthier@ubuntu:~$ sudo dumpkeys | grep -i remove
[sudo] password for gauthier: 
keycode 111 = Remove          
string Remove = "\033[3~"
gauthier@ubuntu:~$
```

0x6f is 111, but I can't see any other relations with what I wrote earlier.

---

**--- EDIT 4 ---**

Interesting, `Ctrl-v` then `delete` makes the cursor flash once, then nothing is displayed. Pressing `Enter` after that gives `^M` then nothing (not even a new prompt).

`Enter` once more yields `: command not found`.

I'm not sure about gnome, I'm on ubuntu studio, Hardy.

Comment: how about more details? like keyboard type, linux distribution...

Comment: What do `showkey -s` and `showkey -k` show when run from a virtual terminal?

Comment: What does `xmodmap -pke | grep -i delete` show when run from a terminal in the X window system (gnome-terminal, xterm, or equivalent)?

Comment: Also what does `sudo dumpkeys | grep -i remove` show?

Comment: Verify that you have the correct keyboard layout selected. Go to `System -> Preferences -> Keyboard`, select the `Layout` options tab. Also check to see if there is a Logitech Ultra-X Cordless / regular keyboard model available. They are listed in Ubuntu Karmic Koala (9.10).

Comment: @mctylr: thanks, I had not my keyboard model selected. Selecting it did not solve the problem though (I don't think I need a restart for that to take effect, right?).

Comment: All the results are correct except for `xev`. If you press `Ctrl-v` then `Delete` at a shell prompt does it show `^[[3~`? Are you running Gnome? On my system, `xev` shows similar results (to yours for Delete) when I press a multimedia key. Have a look in keyboard preferences and keyboard shortcuts to see if anything's not right. And I think you probably do need to do a restart (or at least a log out/in).

Answer (score 3):

Considering that the output of `showkey -s` is as expected, and yet `xev` doesn't show any keypress, one possibility is that the key has been defined as a shortcut in your window manager/desktop environment.

Does the problem arise if you log in as a different user? If not, you've probably inadvertently defined Delete as a shortcut for something that doesn't have an obvious effect.

Comment: Yep, in Ubuntu's "Keyboard-Shortcuts" setup, I had 'Delete' defined where it shouldn't be. My only guess could be that I had another key defined, and pressed 'delete' thinking it would remove the setting, but actually setting it to 'Delete', THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, and as a matter of fact, it was a gnome shortcut getting "Delete" as a key when I was trying to delete the past shortcut. In my particular case, the culprit was Super+L, which I want to use to something else than for Locking the screen.

So the solution is: go to Setup - Keyboard Shortcuts - and search where the Delete keypress was wrongly assigned. To remove the incorrect assignment you need to click on the delete arrow signal on the left of the field, NOT to press the Delete key ( otherwise it thinks it is the shortcut...)

For the sake of completeness, this happens in Gnome, independent of the distro - I am running Arcolinux here.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a shortcut (or Accelerator) I set up in one of my GNOME Extensions to get triggered on pressing <kbd>Del</kbd>. It captured the <kbd>Del</kbd> before any application, making it seem that <kbd>Del</kbd> wasn't working.

Running `xev` and then pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> gave the following output which is very similar to OP's output.

```
$ xev

...

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

### Solution

I then just reassigned another key as the shortcut in that extension and again ran the `xev` command. Pressing <kbd>Del</kbd>  now gave the following output:

```
$ xev

...

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
root 0x6bc, subw 0x0, time 1778784, (829,468), root:(879,581),
state 0x2000, keycode 119 (keysym 0xffff, Delete), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7f) ""
XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7f) ""
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
root 0x6bc, subw 0x0, time 1778899, (829,468), root:(879,581),
state 0x2000, keycode 119 (keysym 0xffff, Delete), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7f) ""
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

The <kbd>Del</kbd> key worked just fine for me after this.